# Is it possible to add Html tags into Spring MVC3 I18N messages.properties file

Tags: spring, internationalization

Given the following MVC3 i18n use:

at a jsp file:

```
<s:message code="clickHere">
```

at message.properties file:

```
clickHere=Please click <a href="http://abc.com">Here</a>
```

a user's browser will display(and the word Here will be a link to `http://abc.com`):
Please click Here

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try

```
<s:message code="clickHere" htmlEscape="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In any case you use ***Thymeleaf***, instead of `th:text`, you should use the `th:utext`.
Example below:

```
# Instead of this
<div th:text="#{message}">text to be replaced</div>

# Use this
<div th:utext="#{message}">text to be replaced</div>
```

You should always keep in mind that using the `th:utext` can cause XSS Attacks.

In the properties file, you will obviously have the following,

```
# In properties
message=Text to be displayed
```